# Amplify Cognito Admin Query listUsersInGroup not working

Tags: amazon-cognito, aws-amplify, amplify-auth-cognito

I am working with AWS Amplify, specifically with Auth; I am trying to get the listUsersInGroup from Cognito pool using the next function in React:

```
import { Auth, API } from 'aws-amplify';

const listUsersInGroup = async (group) => {
    let apiName = 'AdminQueries';
    let path = '/listUsersInGroup';
    let myInit = {
      body: {
        "groupname": group
      }, 
      headers: {
        'Content-Type' : 'application/json',
        Authorization: `${(await Auth.currentSession()).getAccessToken().getJwtToken()}`
      } 
    };    
    const supervisorGet = await API.get(apiName, path, myInit);
  }
```

But the API response is having code 403 and the response brings the message: {"message":"groupname is required"}

I made tests with other HTTP methods like listUsers, listGroups, listGroupsForUser and works correctly.

Can anyone help on this issue?

Answer (score 0):

I found the example below in the [Amplify documenation for admin actions](https://docs.amplify.aws/cli/auth/admin/#example).

It looks like the myInit object you are making is using `body`, but the example has `queryStringParameters`. That's why it's not finding the `groupname` key.

```
let nextToken;

async function listEditors(limit){
  let apiName = 'AdminQueries';
  let path = '/listUsersInGroup';
  let myInit = { 
      queryStringParameters: {
        "groupname": "Editors",
        "limit": limit,
        "token": nextToken
      },
      headers: {
        'Content-Type' : 'application/json',
        Authorization: `${(await Auth.currentSession()).getAccessToken().getJwtToken()}`
      }
  }
  const { NextToken, ...rest } =  await API.get(apiName, path, myInit);
  nextToken = NextToken;
  return rest;
}
```